# I am trying to create Linux users from PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, apache

```
shell_exec("sudo useradd -m $username");

shell_exec("yes $password | sudo passwd $username");
```

The code snippet above successfully creates the user but it does not set the password, am I doing something wrong?

[image]

The $username is the megan user at the bottom of the shadow file

Comment: Shouldn't this be `sudo passwd $username` ?

Comment: That was a mistype in the post only sorry about that.

Comment: `I am trying to create Linux users from PHP` - I'm sure this has great attack potential from security standpoint.

Comment: That may be true but for this use case security is not a concern.

Comment: Can you provide the code or examples of how the variables are being set for this?

Comment: Variables are set using an html form. <?php
 // var_dump($_POST);
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

Comment: You should escape your shell arguments, otherwise they can enter pipes, random commands etc.  So make it ex:  `$username = escapeshellarg($_POST['username']);`
to prevent spaces from ruining things or (more importantly) command injection.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot invoke `passwd` non-interactively. Period.

You *can* supply `useradd` with a pre-computed password hash with the `-p` option, though. [See: `man useradd`]

```php
function os_pw_hash($password) {
    $salt = base64_encode(random_bytes(12)); // 16-byte salt
    return crypt('hunter2', '$6$'.$salt.'$');
}

var_dump( os_pw_hash('hunter2') );
```

Output:

```
string(106) "$6$0LIJoQz2W0vP35Ej$kg75OyhAZb9iAbqa/sO56pXs/peA8wPd4DKv5Al0FllBApBe7BvXUA6Q6fQ3bqpxfz.XH6GWnI.mH6yLfTQil1"
```

You're also going to want to run this [and honestly *all* your shell parameters] through `escapeshellarg()` to make sure metacharacters are properly escaped.

Lastly:

> for this use case security is not a concern

Security is *always a concern*. This is usually *doubly* true for cases when you don't think it should be. I have had users that I unfortunately trusted to know better exploit security holes in internal applications to execute commands with root privileges in order to avoid simply having to make a ticket.

Comment: This mostly worked. I can log into the user when I am already logged in as another account using su megan <- $username, but when I try to log into the account using SSH it gives an error message (Permission denied, please try again.). Also can you explain the significance of the 'hunter2', '$6$' and the last '$'.

Comment: It is simply part of the [`cypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt) format. `$` is just a delimiter, and `6` is the algorithm id for `CRYPT_SHA512`, matching the existing entries you posted. `hunter2` is just an example password. Check your shadow file to see if the hash is there as expected.

Comment: This method mostly did work but I still have the issue that I cant log into the newly created user using an SSH client unless I manually change the password.

Comment: Check your shadow file to see if the hash is there as expected. I can't tell you why it didn't work, you need to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this.

You want as much isolation from the outward facing parts of your system (web pages) from the internal administration. To that end your script should *only* be able to create users within the constraints you set. Write a separate script which takes 2 arguments - a username and a password (although for preference it should generate a random password) which applies THOROUGH validation of the inputs (e.g. no '/' in user name) and give your webserver uid sudo provileges on that script **only** (it could be iwritten n PHP calling adduser directly).

The reason your code isn't working is that `passwd` clears the input buffer before reading the password. And typically it asks for the new password twice - but the prompts and replies vary by context. There are other programs you can use for setting passswords which are more consistent - chpasswd is fairly standard on Linux systems - and as Sammitch says *some* versions of useradd allow the password to be specified at the time the user is created.

Comment: Just want to note my vigorous agreement with all of this.